# The group $\mathbb{C}_{p^\infty}$ has no maximal subgroups

Tags: group-theory, complex-numbers, modules, maximal-subgroup

I am trying to prove that, for $p \in \mathbb{N}$ a prime and $U_m:= \left\{ x \in \mathbb{C}: x^m=1 \right\}$, the multiplicative group $\mathbb{C}_{p^\infty}:= \bigcup\limits_{n\in \mathbb{N}} U_{p^n}$ contains no maximal (proper) subgroups (i.e. maximal $\mathbb{Z}$-submodules).

First off, it's clear that it's an abelian group because if $x,y \in \mathbb{C}_{p^\infty}$, then $x \in U_{p^n}$ and $y \in U_{p^m}$ for some $n, m \in \mathbb{N}$ and then $(xy) \in U_{p^np^m}$.

Supposing $G$ were a maximal subgroup, we'd have that $G \cdot \left\langle x \right\rangle = \mathbb{C}_{p^\infty}$ for all $x \in \mathbb{C}_{p^\infty} \setminus G$. I'm stuck at seeing how this would lead to a contradiction. I was thinking of writing $x=\xi_n^d$, where $\xi_n$ is a primitive root of unity of order $p^n$; this might help because at least primitive roots of unity of different orders are distinct, but I don't know where to take it from here. Obviously, the fact that we're only considering the union over powers of $p$ should come into play somehow.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Hint: If $x,y\in \mathbb{C}_{p^{\infty}}$, then either $\langle x\rangle\subseteq \langle y\rangle$ or $\langle y\rangle\subseteq \langle x\rangle$. So you would necessarily have $G\subseteq\langle x\rangle$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $G$ be a proper subgroup of $\mathbb{C}_{p^\infty}$.

From the chain of proper inclusions
$$
U_{p^0}\subset U_{p^1}\subset U_{p^2}\subset U_{p^3}\subset\cdots
$$
it follows that there must exist a largest nonnegative integer $n$ such that $U_{p^n}\subseteq G$.

If $x\in G$ has order $p^m$ then 
$$
\langle{x}\rangle=U_{p^m}\subseteq G
$$
hence $m\le n$.

It follows that $G=U_{p^n}$, so $G$ is not maximal.

Comment: So we only use that $p$ is prime to infer from $ord(x) | p^n$ that $ord(x) = p^m$, and we only use that the orders are $\textrm{some number}^k$ to see that we have that chain of inclusions. Correct?

Comment: Yes, each $x\in \mathbb{C}_{p^\infty}$ must be an element of $U_{p^m}$ for some nonnegative integer $m$, hence since $p$ is prime, $x$ must have order $p^k$ for some nonnegative integer $k\le m$.